# Keycloak usage in only React application very limited?

Tags: keycloak

So I created a website which shouldn’t be publicly accessible. Therefore I added the keycloak js adapter. Everything works as expected and I am redirected when entering the website url.

But there is a problem. If I use wget on the js/images/css etc. I still can access them because no javascript code is executed and no redirect is performed. How can I make sure that only authenticated users can access these resources? The website is hosted on nginx.

Expected is:

1. User tries to download file
2. User is redirected to keycloak if not authenticated.

Comment: Frontend files js/images/css etc shouldn't contain any sensitive details, so they can be available. Frontend communicates with backend, where is whole bussiness logic/data, so backend must be protected. Keycloak js adapter provides functionality to obtain/manage OIDC token, which will be used for backend (API) calls. So Keycloak js adapter is not limited - it is doing what it should.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't say that the Keycloak js adapter is limited. Its benefit is only very small when you don't have a backend service. I guess the best idea is to add a backend which serves the relevant data to the static website.

Comment: I think you have wrong expectation about Keycloak js adapter. Use OIDC auth on the Nginx level, when you are expecting that also static resources will need authentication. But you will have trouble to have user identity on the frontend side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved see comment under original post.